# Check if window is triggered by watermark passing it

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

If I have a window like this:

```
.apply(Window
    .<String>into(Sessions
        .withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(10)))
    .triggering(AfterWatermark
        .pastEndOfWindow()
        .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))));
```

And it receives data:

```
a -> x (timestamp 0) (received at 20)
a -> y (timestamp 1) (received at 21)
(watermark passes 11) (at 22)
```

I suppose that the window would trigger at times:

- 20 sec, because of an early firing
- 21 sec, because of an early firing
- 22 sec, because of watermark passing the GapDuration

In a `ParDo` function that I apply over the windowed data, is there a way to distinguish early firing from watermark passing the `GapDuration`?

According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768693/is-there-anyway-to-poll-the-system-watermark-of-a-running-data-flow-pipeline) there is no way to get the watermark. If I was able to do that, I could check `max(timestamp) < watermark`. But since I cannot get the watermark, is there any other way to figure out that a window was triggered by watermark passing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `PaneInfo` of the elements in a `DoFn` after the `GroupByKey` by calling [`ProcesContext#pane()`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn.ProcessContext#pane--) and use that to determine the [`Timing`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/PaneInfo.Timing). This will allow you to identify if this as an "on time" firing (due to the watermark passing the end of the window) or a speculative/late firing.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.